# ASP.Net Identity with WebForms to existing SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

I tried the ASP.Net identity and it works fine.
I then tried to get it working with an existing SQL database using the pre-created scripts as provided here: [SQL script for creating an ASP.NET Identity Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677279/SQL-script-for-creating-an-ASP-NET-Identity-Databa)

I changed the default connection string to the one defined in web.config:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDatabaseEntities")
    {
    }
}
```

I foolishly assumed this was all I needed to change since the tables were created and I was pointing it to the SQL database.
When I attempt to register a new user, the error message is: 
{"The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context."}

QUESTION: What am I missing to make this work?  Is there a best practice for implementing Identity with existing SQL databases using Entity Framework?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of EF and Code First or DB First?

Comment: It'll be EF6 using DB first because a SQL database already set up to use EF has been created. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please consider inspecting the `SimpleMembershipInitializer` in Filter folder and `UsersContext` in Model. The sql script for identity miss some tables use by Membership Provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided that since we would be creating a new database that we would just follow the code-first approach.

For those interested I found this [Use ASP.NET Identity on existing DB-Model](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM) and it is VERY good.  I tried following it but got stuck right at the end and didn't want to spend a lot of time on it since CF was decided.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ASP.NET Identity Database** for that.Which is a SQL Database project template for Visual Studio which can be used to create a custom ASP.NET Identity / Membership provider using **Database First** development approach.

Please check below mnetioned link for more info :

[**ASP.NET Identity Database**](http://identity.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I have found this recently.  It creates the database just like the link that I posted above except it has more fields in the User table.  It is something that I was planning on doing as well but this is already done which is great. 
The problem that I'm getting is "ApplicationUser".  So i'm not connecting properly. Are there any configurations that I'm missing? Thanks.